# startup class add db context with encrypted string

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

in my .net core 2.2 application i am trying to create a db context using the following code in the startup.cs ConfigureServices method:'

```
var connectionString = Configuration.GetSection("Appsettings")["MyConnectionString"];

services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
```

my connection string in the appsettings is encrypted though so how would i go about to get my code to work correctly.

I have a service class that is not static or does not contain static methods.There is a Decrypt method.
I can not therefore in startup.cs call MyService.Decrypt(connectionString).

Alternative i could think is to do something like

```
var myService = new MyService();
var decrypted = myService.Decrypt(connectionString);
```

But MyService has its own dependencies which i would then need to pass into the constructor.

I wasn't sure if there was alternative way to do this.

Comment: You get value of connection string in connectionString variable?

Comment: Decript the string before passing to dbconnect..

Comment: @Aldert i have service class that is doing the decrypting so i should call my service class to decrypt? I'll have to new it up wont i to get access to the methods as i wont be able to use DI at this point.

Answer (score 1):

The `StartUp` class can be injected with dependencies. You can do something like this:

```
private IConfiguration _configuration;
  public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }
```

**Apply like this:**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
string theEncryptedOne =_configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnectionString");
string decrypted =//Do something with the encrypted string. 
//Pass it when done.
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(option=>option.UseSqlServer(decryptedString));
}
```